# What is the different between using accelerometer&gyroscope and accelerometer&Magnetometer to find the orientation?

Tags: android, orientation, sensors, gyroscope, magnetometer

Using accelerometer&gyroscope to find orientation need to integrate gyroscope and need to use filter. The program will become very complicated. I try to use this method but I can't control the time interval of getting sensor data. Therefore, I can't really figure out how to do it.

Using accelerometer&Magnetometer seems easier to do it.

Then, what is the different between these two method?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Accelerometer and gyroscope measures acceleration and orientation along linear and rotational axis while magnetometer and accelerometer measures orientation along linear axis and magnetic fields produced by surface of earth. I went through a module that has an inbuilt filter on the sensor shield and the code also worked well. This is 3D Accelerometer 3D Gyroscope 3D Magnetometer.

https://www.controleverything.com/content/Accelorometer?sku=LSM9DS0_I2CS

You can use the code according to the language you desire

https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/LSM9DS0

Thanks..